# array_values_database and k means

Tags: php, mysql, k-means

I used K-means algorithm. The function get 2 parameters: an array that consists of product average cost per user and an integer that represents the number of clusters `( kmeans($pin, 2) )`.

I want to put into the database the letter `A` if the user buys expensive products and `B` if not. The function that return the results is the following:

```
function kmeans_get_cluster_values($clusters, $data) {
    $n = array(); $values = array();
    foreach($clusters as $dataKey => $cluster) {  
        $values[$cluster][] = $data[$dataKey].' <br/>'; 
    }
    return $values;
}
```

The output is:

```
Array (
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => 346.98
        [1] => 214.42
        [2] => 280.26
    ) 
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => 46.99
        [1] => 13.78
    )
)
```

Numbers `346.98`, `214.42` and `280.26` are in the first cluster and numbers `46.99` and `13.78` are in the second cluster. The problem is that I can't find  a way to separate this array.

For example I want to insert into my MySQL database the first cluster that consist of 3 numbers and then the second cluster and so on. As a matter of fact I want to insert into the database the letters `A` or `B` for the number of cluster.

Comment: PHP and MySQL are just the wrong tools for this. You really should look at the algorithm. It seems you got a much too simple implementation to be useful in practise (plus, I bet it will be really slow).

Comment: I have already developed an eshop with php and mysql and I want to use some algorithms for clustering etc. Can I use some tool-program for this? In other words what do you suggest me ?

Comment: Try out various tools, and see what works for you. There is no one size fits all, you will have to find your own preferences. YMMV